# Lodash ainda é necessário com ES6+?

Tags: javascript

Vejo que em 2020 lodash não é mais necessário, conseguimos fazer 90% do que ele faz com ES6+ e rapido, então fico com a dúvida cruel, é realmente necessário instalar uma dependência gigante como essa nos projetos? Sei que quando estamos falando de Angular podemos usar o RXJS, mas me refiro ao Javascript em geral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Lodash, assim como o jQuery, MooTools ou RxJS são caixas de ferramentas. Ainda que usando ES6 muita da funcionalidade que o Lodash oferece precisa de muitas linhas de código para implementar e o Lodash garante ferramentas testadas em cenário de produção, isso é muito importante.

O teu receio de importar uma dependência gigante não é correta. O Lodash permite que importes somente as ferramentas que precises usando a sintaxe:

```
import clamp from 'lodash/clamp';
import toInteger from 'lodash/toInteger';
```

Eu uso muito o `debounce` por exemplo, se fosse escrever essa função sozinho teria de a testar e não ia ficar curta nas primeiras iterações.

Tendo dito isto claro que é importante reduzir sempre o numero de dependências externas. Se não precisas do Lodash, ou o que precisas é fácil e seguro de fazer com ferramentas caseiras então vai nessa direção.

Comment: "ferramentas caseiras" aqui no brasil às vezes tem uma conotação levemente negativa, dependendo da região, sugerindo que talvez seja "precária", não sei se é a intenção. Talvez "ferramentas próprias" seja mais neutro (mas vai mesmo da intenção - não tem problema nenhum na sua frase, só quis mencionar - depois deleto o comment)

Comment: @Bacco boa, não sabia dessa diferênça. _Ferramentas próprias_ no sentido de não públicas é o que queria dizer.

Answer (score 0):

Mas o propósito do Lodash é diferente. O ES6 é, a grosso modo, uma especificação do Javascript, um conjunto de regras que vão regular as implementações da linguagem. O propósito do Lodash é facilitar o JavaScript, ajudando a trabalhar com matrizes, números, objetos, sequências de caracteres entre outras coisas.